# JQuery Question - Append value to hidden input field?

Tags: jquery, automation, textfield

I have three form fields: name, first name, and lastname.  The name field is hidden and I'm trying to set the value to the firstname + lastname on keypress.  I'm also trying to format it so that the characters are all lowercase and spaces are transformed into dashes.

So:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="John John" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe" />
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="john-john-doe" />
```

I've been trying to use the following code, but it's not working...

```
            $('input[name=field_firstname[0][value]]').keyup(function() {
                    var firstname = $('input[name=field_firstname[0][value]]').val();
                    var lastname = $('input[name=field_lastname[0][value]]').val();
                    $('input[name=name]').val(firstname.replace(/\s/g, "-").toLowerCase()+lastname.replace(/\s/g, "-").toLowerCase());
            });

            $('input[name=field_lastname[0][value]]').keyup(function() {
                    var firstname = $('input[name=field_firstname[0][value]]').val();
                    var lastname = $('input[name=field_lastname[0][value]]').val();
                    $('input[name=name]').val(firstname.replace(/\s/g, "-").toLowerCase()+lastname.replace(/\s/g, "-").toLowerCase());
            });
```

Comment: Maybe that's just a matter of taste, but you could use `id` instead of `name`. The jQuery syntax would be much clearer: that would be `$('input#firstname')` instead of `$('input[name="firstname"]')`, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing some context, but I don't think you can use attribute selectors like that. To get at the firstname field, you'd say: `input[name='firstname']`.

You're also doing the same thing twice, which is always a good reason to give things some extra thought. For example, you can do both `keyup`s in one shot:

```
$("input[name='firstname'], input[name='lastname']").keyup(...);
```

You can make things a lot easier by using IDs, though. For example, take this HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="John John" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="Doe" />
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="sanitized_name" value="john-john-doe" />
```

You'd use the following code snippit:

```
$('#firstname, #lastname').keyup(function() {
  var fullname = $('#firstname').val() + ' ' + $('#lastname').val();
  $('#sanitized_name').val(fullname.replace(/\s/g, '-').toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit `[0][value]` as in:

```
$('input[name=field_firstname]') // removed [0][value]
```

Not entirely sure why you put that in there.

Also, you might want to use `.blur()` instead of `.keyup()`, saves you a lot of redundant repetition. Even better, concat the fields on a `.submit()` because thats when you care about it anyways. Think about it, "Jhon Doe" means 16 lookups and 8 concatenations when using `.keyup()` along with jQuery processes to get it done.

**addendum**

Seeing this a few times now, people put invalid/problematic characters inside id attributes like `[0][value]`, this is invalid to jQuery as it recognises it as a css expression rather then part of an id. `document.getElementById( "bla[0]" );` does seem to work however so if you really have to (or are too lazy to fix it), you can do the following:

```
$( document.getElementById( "bla[0][value]" ) ) //etc
```